# No logro obtener los datos de mi Database en Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Estoy utilizando Kotlin y no logro acceder a mi data base en firebase ya verifique y toda mi configuración esta bien.

Como lo indica Google coloque todas las dependencias necesarias, pero sigue sin funcionar, si aparece conectada mi app a firebase no se cual es el problema.

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val database = Firebase.database.reference

        val listener = object  : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val data = snapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvData).text = "Firebase remote: $data"
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        }

        val dataRef = database.child("hola_firebase").child("data")

        dataRef.addValueEventListener(listener)

    }
}```



[![Imagen de mi database][1]][1]


 [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7SlQ.png
````

Comment: Haz Log en tus métodos y revisa el LogCat. Por ejemplo, en `onDataChange()` agrega esto:  `Log.d("AAA","Datos:"+data)` y en `onCancelled()` agrega esto: `Log.d("AAA","ERROR: "+error.toException())` Dinos qué ves en el Logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre resolver el problema lo probé en un dispositivo físico y observe que funciono, pero en el emulador seguía sin funcionar entonces decidí formatear la información del emulador y listo funciona sin problemas.